# How to Put $expand Property in groupby query in ODATA

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using WebApi 2 with odata 5.3.1.

I am using `groupby` query, by implementing my own *`GroupBy()`* custom function.

```
http://localhost:51738/odata/Document?$apply=groupby((Category),%20aggregate(Documents/$count%20as%20Total))
```

But in new database the Category Property is a navigation property & we can achieve it by using `$expand`.
So how to use `$expand` query inside `groupby` query?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make group by query compatible with navigation property & it's supporting in odata 5.9.1 library.
In `Employee` entity there is a Navigation property called `Classes`,
So we can use group by query like this

```
http://localhost:51738/odata/Employee?$apply=groupby((Classes/Id)
```